# How can I auto build SPA when deploy to heroku

Tags: vue.js, heroku, npm, deployment, vue-cli

I'm learning deploy my Vue app to Heroku. I was deploy my code to Heroku and I want it auto build my code to `dist/` folder. I tried config the package file. But I always get an error. What is the best way to auto build Vue app after deploy?

**My code structure:**

```
api/
auth/
package.json

client/
__package.json
__src/
```

**Root package file**

```
"scripts": {
  "postinstall": "npm install --prefix client",
  "build": "cd client && npm run build"
}
```

**Package file in Vue app**

```
{
  "name": "vue",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome": "^1.1.8",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.6.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.9",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.6.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.6.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.6.0",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "^0.1.3",
    "animate.css": "^3.7.0",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.5.2",
    "vue": "^2.6.6",
    "vue-axios": "^2.1.4",
    "vue-class-component": "^6.0.0",
    "vue-fullcalendar": "^1.0.9",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^7.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-session": "^1.0.0",
    "vue-textarea-autosize": "^1.0.4",
    "vue-toasted": "^1.1.26",
    "vuejs-datepicker": "^1.5.3",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex-class": "^0.3.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^3.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^3.4.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.4.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21"
  }
}
```

**Log on Heroku**

```
-----> Node.js app detected

-----> Creating runtime environment

       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false

-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)

       Resolving node version 10.x...
       Downloading and installing node 10.15.3...
       Using default npm version: 6.4.1

-----> Restoring cache
       - node_modules (not cached - skipping)

-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules (package.json)

       > gym_schedule@1.0.0 postinstall /tmp/build_d350166995249e94786090e39036fa51
       > npm install --prefix server && npm install --prefix client


       > nodemon@1.18.10 postinstall /tmp/build_d350166995249e94786090e39036fa51/server/node_modules/nodemon
       > node bin/postinstall || exit 0

       Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
        > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate

       added 772 packages from 997 contributors and audited 14644 packages in 20.244s
       found 0 vulnerabilities

       added 34 packages from 39 contributors and audited 32176 packages in 15.597s
       found 0 vulnerabilities

       up to date in 37.279s
       found 0 vulnerabilities

-----> Build
       Running build

       > gym_schedule@1.0.0 build /tmp/build_d350166995249e94786090e39036fa51
       > cd client && npm run build


       > vue@0.1.0 build /tmp/build_d350166995249e94786090e39036fa51/client
       > vue-cli-service build

sh: 1: vue-cli-service: not found
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! vue@0.1.0 build: `vue-cli-service build`
```

Comment: It says `vue-cli-service: not found`. So it's either not installed, or it can't find it, or it's not executable.

Comment: @RolfBly I just updated a package file in vue app and fully heroku log. I think build command run when `vue-cli-service` is installing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the first half you're doing great: `package.json#build` precises the script to be ran in order to be built on Heroku's remote environment.

The thing is, in this environment, your global packages (the one you installed through `npm install -g <package-name>` are not available! This is the case for `vue-cli-service`, which has to be included in `package.json#devDependencies`, or simply run `npm install --save-dev vue-cli-service` in your local repo and deploy again.

Comment: I just updated a package file in vue app and fully heroku log. In this package file, I have `vue-cli-service` in `devDependencies`. I think a built command run when the packages are installing.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. Heroku will ignore the packages in `devDependencies`. I was turn off `heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false YARN_PRODUCTION=false` and Heroku work fine.

Heroku's document: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#build-behavior

Answer (score 0):

I can see on your structure that you have a client folder with a package.json which includes the vue devDependencies. This problem can be solved by moving your vue devDependencies to the root package.json devDependencies.

A solution that I implemented in order to auto build the dist folder in Heroku, was to create a nodejs server in the root folder. The server.js has the following:

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const serveStatic = require('serve-static');

let app = express();
app.use(serveStatic(__dirname + '/client/dist'));

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
});
```

The root package.json has the following scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build",
 },
```

Remember to include the devDependencies from vue in the root package.json. The start script will be automatically executed in Heroku and the heroku-postbuild will be executed after Heroku installs dependencies of the root file. In this case it will go to the client and install the dependencies of the client and build the dist folder.

One of the problems I had with this approach was that the express module could not be found by heroku even when it was working locally. To solve this issue, i needed to express in the root package.json from devDependencies to dependencies. More info regarding this issue [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys) (Section Missing Modules).

More helpful links to implement my approach can be found [here](https://dev.to/jmbejar/how-to-quickly-deploy-a-vuejs-app-to-heroku-5b0f) and [here](https://medium.com/binarcode/deploying-vue-apps-to-heroku-the-right-way-26b11c1ae5cd).